# Прошу помочь разобраться в реализации оформления контента в Балуне

Tags: yandex-maps-api

На сайте map.fit-n-go.ru отображаются метки с контентом локации. Необходимо допилить контент в каждой метке

Вопросы:

1. Возможно ли увеличивать картинку контента при нажатии? Например как в этом примере- https://codernote.ru/jquery/uvelichenie-izobrazheniya-po-kliku-new/
2. Возможно ли использовать несколько фото на 1 метке в виде карусели?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа. Не задавайте сразу несколько вопросов.